# Error when using ligGDX project generator

Tags: libgdx

When I try to generate new project in libGDX project generator I get error message like this:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11'.

The thing is that it generates project just fine on my PC, but now I cannot do it on my laptop. Any ideas why is this happening?

Both run Windows 10 with the newest JDK, I use the same settings for generator on both.

Comment: Which version do you use? Sounds like an out-dated gradle version.

Comment: I downloaded the newest generator version. Don't know about gradle, never really used it, I am not sure how it works